# Проблема с RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbeanphp

```
require "rb.php";
R::setup('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db,$user,$password);
$Type = R::dispense( 'Type' );
R::store($TypeUser);
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught RedBeanPHP\RedException: Invalid type: Type in /storage/ssd5/276/3652276/public_html/online/rb.php:12675   
> Stack trace:   
> #0 /storage/ssd5/276/3652276/public_html/online/rb.php(10723): RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODB), 'Type', 1, false)   
> #1 /storage/ssd5/276/3652276/public_html/online/registration of physical user1.php(10): RedBeanPHP\Facade::dispense('Type')   
> #2 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/276/3652276/public_html/online/rb.php on line 12675
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не используйте с RB имена таблиц с нижним подчеркиванием (_). Час провозился пока понял это.

Answer (score 0):

> You can dispense any type of bean you like, as long as the type name
>   consists of **lowercase alphabetical characters**,

это у них написано на сайте

Возможно, в строке 
`$Type = R::dispense( 'Type' );`
напишите `Type` в нижнем регистре, хотя не уверен на 100%

Answer (score 0):

Не пишите в `R::dispense(...)` слова с ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ буквами.

Столбцы и названия БД можно писать заглавными, в `Red Bean PHP` лучше писать в нижнем регистре.

Ранее сталкивался с подобной ошибкой.